# For loop and modulus not executing properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that lets the user input the amount of digits required, and then it will swap the first and last digits and then print out new digits after adding 6 with a modulus of 10.

I can't seem to get it to calculate/print correctly.

For example if I input 92821, it will swap the 9 and the 1, then add 6 to each digit with modulus 10, so it will print out 48487.

My problem is when I input 597, it should output 351, but it outputs as 053.
When I input 1050, it should output as 6617, but it outputs as 6616.

```
 11 #include <stdio.h>
 12
 13 //pointers
 14 void replace(int *a, int *b, int n);
 15 void swap(int *a, int *b)
 16 {
 17     int temp = *a;
 18     *a = *b;
 19     *b = temp;
 20 }
 21
 22 int main(void)
 23 {
 24     int n, i, input[n], newInput[n];
 25
 26     //asks for number of digits
 27     printf("Enter total number of digits: ");
 28     scanf("%d", &n);
 29
 30     //user input
 31     printf("Enter a number: ");
 32     for (i=0; i<n; i++)
 33     scanf("%1d", &input[i]);
 34
 35     //replaces first and last number before printing
 36     replace(input, newInput, n);
 37     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
 38     printf("%d", newInput[i]);
 39
 40     return 0;
 41 }
 42
 43 //using replace pointer
 44 void replace (int a[], int b[], int n)
 45 {
 46    int i;
 47    //loops program until input is 0
 48    for (i = 0;i<=n; i++)
 49
 50    //adds 6 to input. Modulus 10
 51    *(b+i) = (*(a+i) + 6) % 10;
 52
 53    //using swap pointer
 54    swap(b, b+4);
 55
 56 }
```

Comment: Remove the line numbers; they don't add any value to the question.

Comment: @cad I suspect the OP uses vi or some similar editor, the line numbers are a good sign and mean that they copied the code directly from the editor.

Comment: You don't indent the `for` body and it seems intentional, you should.

Comment: @cad It's DRM, now you can't "steal" the code.

Comment: Actually, I would like to see MORE line numbers in SO posts.  About once a month, some poster identifies the line that is referenced in some compiler error message, the rest of the time a line is shown, we have to guess:(

Answer (score 6):

## Major

1. The line

   ```
   int n, i, input[n], newInput[n];
   ```

   exhibits undefined behavior because the value of `n` is indeterminate (as with any uninitialized, automatic variable) but you use the variable to define the VLAs nevertheless.

   Move the VLA definitions to after `n` was initialized, i.e., after the `scanf` call.
2. Check the return value of `scanf`, that is, the number of matches. If a user enters a letter instead of a digit, the variable will remain uninitialized and with an indeterminate value, most probably yielding undefined behavior.
3. Since you access the `i`<sup>th</sup> member of the array on the line

   ```
   *(b+i) = (*(a+i) + 6) % 10;
   ```

   the last access will be out of range because

   ```
   for (i = 0;i<=n; i++)
   ```

   will assign the value `n` to `i`. Indexing starts at `0`, so accessing `array[n]` is undefined behavior. **Mind you:** a pointer alone to that location does **not** yield undefined behavior.

## Minor

1. On the line

   ```
   *(b+i) = (*(a+i) + 6) % 10;
   ```

   Why use dereferencing when the subscript operator is so much more readable? Replace the line with

   ```
   b[i] = (a[i] + 6) % 10;
   ```

Comment: I tried to upvote it, but I used up all my votes hours ago when downvoting all the hopeless homework due in tomorrow:(   If I'm still awake later, when I get the next tranche of votes, I'll upvote this before opening fire on the assignments again:)

Comment: @MartinJames lolz I didn't even know that was possible... but thanks anyway, it's the thought that counts. :-)

Comment: @cad - sadly, it's not only possible, but normal:(  I have favourited this question and will get you your upvote later!

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Just one comment, specifically referenced to point 1, this construct, legal for C11, will generate a warning about local 'n' used without being initialized, this means that the he didn't take care of compiler warnings.

Comment: @Frankie_C Does the standard require the issuance of a diagnostic in that case? If not, I would not make any note concerning this. Otherwise, yeah, valid point.

Comment: The rule is the same as any use of uninitialized var. The compiler is generating code to allocate memory for an array with an inconsistent size value. Any decent C compiler will issue a warning. Just put the line in a source file and invoke compiler to check. C++ can handle it differently maybe, but we are talking of plain C.